# How to use the xml csv-parser package in a transform? (namespace give invalid obj ref)

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xml-parsing, w3c

I have a need to transform CSV into XML.

I would like to do it in one step with xslt.

I read with great interest about the [W3C csv-parser package](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#csv-example-default-functionality). The documentation shows an example which declares a namespace of

```
xmlns:csv="http://example.com/csv"
```

at the top of the document and then goes on to say that it will be using the csv-parser package

```
 <xsl:use-package name="http://example.com/csv-parser" 
                package-version="*"/>
```

In the Netbeans (8.2) IDE when I make my own copy of the example given to transform csv to render, the output page generated in the (IE 11.1006) browser states: " The first argument to the non-static Java function 'parse' is not a valid object reference."

When I look up the urls provided above I only see a page title, no packages. Should I? Where is the browser loading the package from otherwise?

I think that the error message is saying that the package reference is bad. Am I not understanding something about the W3C (w3.org) documentation? Are they only suggesting an interface guidline? Do they not provide implementation?

For convenience, here is a copy of the code provided at the hyperlink above:

````
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:csv="http://example.com/csv"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs csv"
   version="3.0">

   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:use-package name="http://example.com/csv-parser" 
                    package-version="*"/>

   <!-- example input "file"  -->
   <xsl:variable name="input" as="xs:string">
       name,id,postal code
       "Abel Braaksma",34291,1210 KA
       "Anders Berglund",473892,9843 ZD
   </xsl:variable>

   <!-- entry point -->
   <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
       <xsl:copy-of select="csv:parse($input)"/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>```
````

Comment: XSLT 3 packages are supported by Saxon 9.8 and 9.9, I have no idea whether NetBeans integrates with any of those implementations. Furthermore, even if you run those Saxon versions from the command line, for your last snippet to run you will need to tell Saxon in a command line option `-lib` or a configuration file where it can find any modules like the one you want to use, unfortunetely the XSLT `use-package` does not allow to suggest a package location.

Answer (score 1):

How to provide package locations to an XSLT processor is processor specific, for Saxon 9 from the command line you can use the `-lib` option to provide file names of packages you want to use or you can use a configuration file that has the adequate section e.g. to load the package directly from the GitHub repository of the XSLT 3 test suite

```
<configuration edition="HE" xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration">
     <xsltPackages>
          <package name="http://example.com/csv-parser" version="1.0"
               sourceLocation="https://github.com/w3c/xslt30-test/raw/master/tests/decl/package/package-100.xsl"
          />
     </xsltPackages>
</configuration>
```

So you basically need to make sure you safe the package you want to use (i.e. the source code you have found in the spec) to a local file, then you can run Saxon 9.8 or later from the command line using the `-it -xsl:your-xslt-code.xsl -lib:package-file.xsl` options or you provide a configuration file with `-config:config.xml`.

At https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hwphT you can see it in action a different way, there Saxon 9 runs the XPath 3.1 `transform` function in XQuery code to run the code of some XSLT provide inline against a configuration node also provided inline which directly references the package's source code from the W3C test suite GitHub repository.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make such a complete answer. Unfortunately the point of my use-case was to give the customer an xslt they could use for transforming a csv data file loaded into a plain-old-browser-window. Looks like csv-parser will require customer to (gasp) install java and the saxon jar. Current solution is to (1) run a batch of regex substitution commands on the csv file to get to a very generic xml doc. (2) Then load the transform in the browser before the generic xml file. It works, and transforms the data as per the xslt, but it's more like two steps, clunky.

Comment: If you want to use XSLT 3 you need to install an XSLT 3 processor. Saxon 9 also exists in a .NET version so it doesn't have to be Java. Not sure why you use NetBeans if Java makes you gasp, isn't that a Java IDE?

Comment: "will require customer to (gasp) install java"

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of the csv-parser example in the XSLT 3.0 specification is as a worked example of how to write packages and use them in an application; it wasn't intended primarily as a working piece of code, though you could certainly use it that way if you want.

A version of the librqry package is included in the XSLT 3.0 test suite at

https://github.com/w3c/xslt30-test/blob/master/tests/decl/package/package-100.xsl

The principal author was Michael Sperberg-McQueen, though other members of the WG contributed. Introducing the package, the specification states "For simplicity of exposition, the example shows a simple, naive implementation; a realistic CSV parser would be more complicated and make the example harder to follow." - this is Michael Sp-McQ being characteristically modest.

But the code was written primarily as a usability test of XSLT 3.0 packaging features, and of course it requires XSLT 3.0 to run it.

You say "when I look up the urls above", but these are not URLs, they are URIs - identifiers, not locations. A URI in the domain example.com is used because it's an example.

I'm not quite sure what the error "The first argument to the non-static Java function 'parse' is not a valid object reference." means, but I strongly suspect it arises because you are not using an XSLT 3.0 processor. In XSLT 1.0, a function call to a prefixed function name is interpreted as a call to an external function (typically a Java method if it's a Java processor), and I suspect that's what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Michael, for clarifying the uri/url confusion. I can grab the file from github and put it in the same dir as the xslt, but as you pointed out - it seems the java processor is looking for an external (java?) function, not an xslt package. Follow-up question: How does one know where to find the actual source the uri references? Eg: if I want to copy it down local, how do I know where to get it? Thx

Comment: Some of these URIs are namespaces; these don't have any associated resources. See the explanation at http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm. In the case of XSLT 3.0 packages, the source and compiled code for a package might exist at many different locations (just like a Java package), and individual XSLT processors will provide a way for you to tell them where to look for source and/or object code.